# MySQL Select and display rows of 16 times

Tags: mysql

I have a query:

```
SELECT OGLOSZENIA.Id_ogloszenia, TYP_NADWOZIA.Nazwa_nadwozie, OGLOSZENIA.Opis,
WOJEWODZTWA.Nazwa_wojewodztwo, OGLOSZENIA.Miasto, OGLOSZENIA.Rocznik, OGLOSZENIA.Cena, 
OGLOSZENIA.id_model, MARKI.Nazwa_marka, MODELE.Nazwa_model, ZDJECIA.Zdjecie, 
SILNIK.Nazwa_silnik, KOLORY.Nazwa_kolor, OGLOSZENIA.Moc, OGLOSZENIA.Pojemnosc
FROM OGLOSZENIA, MARKI, MODELE, ZDJECIA, WOJEWODZTWA, TYP_NADWOZIA, SILNIK, KOLORY
WHERE OGLOSZENIA.Id_koloru = KOLORY.Id_koloru AND 
OGLOSZENIA.Id_silnik = SILNIK.Id_silnik AND 
OGLOSZENIA.Id_kategoria = TYP_NADWOZIA.Id_kategoria AND 
MODELE.Id_marka = MARKI.Id_marka AND 
OGLOSZENIA.Id_model = MODELE.Id_model  AND 
OGLOSZENIA.Id_ogloszenia = ZDJECIA.Id_ogloszenia 
ORDER BY OGLOSZENIA.Id_ogloszenia DESC;
```

In DB I have a 3 rows in 'OGLOSZENIA', but when I do query, display 48 rows. 1 row in DB display 16 times. Where is problem?

Comment: sry, but what about generalizing variables into the English Language before posting, just a suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 8 tables but only 6 join conditions. One condition is missing and  the result is a `CROSS JOIN`.

The `FROM` part:

```
FROM OGLOSZENIA, MARKI, MODELE, ZDJECIA
   , WOJEWODZTWA, TYP_NADWOZIA, SILNIK, KOLORY
WHERE OGLOSZENIA.Id_koloru = KOLORY.Id_koloru AND 
OGLOSZENIA.Id_silnik = SILNIK.Id_silnik AND 
OGLOSZENIA.Id_kategoria = TYP_NADWOZIA.Id_kategoria AND 
MODELE.Id_marka = MARKI.Id_marka AND 
OGLOSZENIA.Id_model = MODELE.Id_model  AND 
OGLOSZENIA.Id_ogloszenia = ZDJECIA.Id_ogloszenia
```

should be written using the explicit `JOIN` syntax:

```
FROM OGLOSZENIA
  JOIN SILNIK  ON OGLOSZENIA.Id_silnik = SILNIK.Id_silnik 
  JOIN MODELE  ON OGLOSZENIA.Id_model = MODELE.Id_model
  JOIN MARKI   ON MODELE.Id_marka = MARKI.Id_marka 
  JOIN KOLORY  ON OGLOSZENIA.Id_koloru = KOLORY.Id_koloru 
  JOIN ZDJECIA ON OGLOSZENIA.Id_ogloszenia = ZDJECIA.Id_ogloszenia 
  JOIN TYP_NADWOZIA ON OGLOSZENIA.Id_kategoria = TYP_NADWOZIA.Id_kategoria
  JOIN WOJEWODZTWA  ON  ???
```

Answer (score 1):

If you rewrite your query with explicit join syntax you'll see right away that not everything is being joined properly:

```
SELECT OGLOSZENIA.Id_ogloszenia, TYP_NADWOZIA.Nazwa_nadwozie, OGLOSZENIA.Opis,
WOJEWODZTWA.Nazwa_wojewodztwo, OGLOSZENIA.Miasto, OGLOSZENIA.Rocznik, OGLOSZENIA.Cena, 
OGLOSZENIA.id_model, MARKI.Nazwa_marka, MODELE.Nazwa_model, ZDJECIA.Zdjecie, 
SILNIK.Nazwa_silnik, KOLORY.Nazwa_kolor, OGLOSZENIA.Moc, OGLOSZENIA.Pojemnosc

    FROM OGLOSZENIA 
    join MARKI ???
    join MODELE on MODELE.Id_marka = MARKI.Id_marka and OGLOSZENIA.Id_model = MODELE.Id_model
    join ZDJECIA ???
    join WOJEWODZTWA on OGLOSZENIA.Id_ogloszenia = ZDJECIA.Id_ogloszenia 
    join TYP_NADWOZIA on OGLOSZENIA.Id_kategoria = TYP_NADWOZIA.Id_kategoria
    join SILNIK on OGLOSZENIA.Id_silnik = SILNIK.Id_silnik
    join KOLORY on OGLOSZENIA.Id_koloru = KOLORY.Id_koloru

ORDER BY OGLOSZENIA.Id_ogloszenia DESC;
```

This means that you're getting a cross join on a couple of tables which is causing your output to be multiplied.

Besides using the explicit JOIN syntax I would also suggest using table aliases to help you clean up and understand the query. Something like:

```
SELECT o.Id_ogloszenia, tn.Nazwa_nadwozie, o.Opis,
w.Nazwa_wojewodztwo, o.Miasto, o.Rocznik, o.Cena, 
o.id_model,  mk.Nazwa_marka, mo.Nazwa_model, z.Zdjecie, 
s.Nazwa_silnik, k.Nazwa_kolor, o.Moc, o.Pojemnosc

    FROM OGLOSZENIA as o
    join MARKI as mk ???
    join MODELE as mo on mo.Id_marka =  mk.Id_marka and o.Id_model = mo.Id_model
    join ZDJECIA as z ???
    join WOJEWODZTWA as w on o.Id_ogloszenia = z.Id_ogloszenia -- THIS IS INCORRECT...
    join TYP_NADWOZIA as tn on o.Id_kategoria = tn.Id_kategoria
    join SILNIK as s on o.Id_silnik = s.Id_silnik
    join KOLORY as k on o.Id_koloru = k.Id_koloru

ORDER BY o.Id_ogloszenia DESC;
```

TO proceed forward I would suggest trimming out some of the tables, narrowing to the result set you need and then add more joins to get the details of your final query. Iterate from simple to more complex.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT OGLOSZENIA.Id_ogloszenia, TYP_NADWOZIA.Nazwa_nadwozie ...
```